# Передать http post и сделать скриншот

Tags: php, post, curl

Есть данные в ассоциативном массиве, вида
**$data**

```
lname=>***
fname=>***
mname=>***
docseries=>***
docnumber=>***
```

Нужно передать `http` запрос серверу и сделать скриншот той страницы, которую отдаст сервер. Не понимаю, как это сделать.

Попытался curl'ом отдать ему данные

```
              $myCurl = curl_init();
              curl_setopt_array($myCurl, array(
                  CURLOPT_URL => 'https://123123123.action',
                  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
                  CURLOPT_POST => true,
                  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => http_build_query($DATA)
              ));
              $response = curl_exec($myCurl);
              curl_close($myCurl);

              $telegram->sendMessage([ 'chat_id' => $chat, 'text' => $response ]);
```

На условно `https://123123123.action` передаются данные post методом с другой страницы. Я пытаюсь это реализовать через своего бота в телеграм.

В ответ на этот запрос curl я получаю бесконечные ответы

```
lname=>***
fname=>***
mname=>***
docseries=>***
docnumber=>***
```

Почему? Как это исправить? Спасибо

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В итоге отправил GET, но серверу все. Скриншот генерировал сервис

**Функция:**

```
function SiteScreenshot($url, $chat, $resolution='1720x1080', $size='1920', $format='png') {
  $Filename = $chat.".jpg";
  // Директория где лежат скрины
  $ScreenshotDirectory = "screens/";
  // Проверяем если есть такой файл в папке скринов

    $Image = @file_get_contents("http://mini.s-shot.ru/".$resolution."/".$size."/".$format."/?".$url);
    $OpenFile = fopen($ScreenshotDirectory.$Filename, "w+");
    // Сохраняем изображение
    $Write = fwrite($OpenFile, $Image);
    return $ScreenshotDirectory.$Filename;
}
```

И сам **обработчик**

```
$site = "http://example.com?".$string;
SiteScreenshot($site,$chat);

$path_to_photo = "https://domen.ru/screens/";
```

Answer (score 0):

Лучше попробовать через PhantomJS (или форк CapserJS)

У них даже в базовом примере (читай hello world) есть данный функционал

Comment: У меня нет личного сервера пока что. Пользуюсь хостингом. Туда же нельзя поставить эту библиотеку

Comment: а это уже от вашего хостинга зависит  https://www.casperjs.org/  почитайте.

в любом случае вы можете использовать VPS и ставить и запускать там что душе угодно.